# Database Designing One-to-One Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, database-design

I am a beginner in database design. I am a little bit confused about a 
one-to-one relationship.

I have a table called **task_tbl** and I want the user to rate a task (the rating will be out of 5, 1 to 5 stars). I am a little bit nervous about how to do it; should I create another table called **rate_tbl**, or should I put it in **task_tbl** in a column named **rate**? The task can have only 1 rating in the database which will be from 1 to 5.

Here is my **task_tbl**:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `end_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,       
    `created_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
```

Comment: 1:1 is rarely needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relating Task and its rating(I suppose you mean rating, not rate of food in hotel).

So as per normalization , you should make another table , `rating_table` which will have predefined values from `0` to `10` as rating will be in between 0 to 10.

Now you need another table  `tasks_ratings` which will have `task_id` and `rating_id` and `user_id`.

See , rating from 0 to 10 will be fetched from `rating_table` which will be shown to users in web browser, and their Response (the rating they give) will be stored in `tasks_ratings` table with user_id , task_id and rating_id.

Now if you want to calculate average rating use `avg()` from the `tasks_ratings` table by taking task id from task table.

Comment: Sir I am not talking about $ rate i am talking about five-start-rating when a user click on second star it should store 2 in Database,if he click on 5 number star then it should store 6 in database.

Comment: @usama , then you should  already clear it in question. anyways check updated answer.

Comment: Sir here you are creating third table then it means it will become Many-to-Many Relationship  is it right sir...if it is then why are we doing this why are we creating third table can't we add userid and taskid  in the rating table.So that it will become on-to-one relation.

Comment: yes its one to one relationship as we see one Task can have 1 rating only (say its 7). But see, you will always want user to show WHAT rating he gave . See if i come back tomorrow on same task page, I will be able to see what rating I gave. Second reason is : You will (For sure) have to calculate average rating of task given by 10000 users. So for taking `AVG()` , average , you need ALL ratings for THAT task. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: how can it be one-to-one relationship because 1 task can have many ratings by user as you say so it will be one-to-many relationship.

Comment: See it can be One to One relationship if you consider Average rating of task like say Task: Studying , Rating 6.6 (this is average) . Now **Only** to get Average rating we use One to Many relationship(many ratings). So in short it is One to Many if you consider 10000 ratings given by people , but if you want Only average rating(you will be doing this only) , its One To One( Task Studying, Rating : 6.6)

Comment: Actually speaking : To show Avarage rating , its one to one, but to store what task has What rating given by Each people , its One to Many relationship. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @usama , Glad to help you **`:)`** . And I am not sir , I am just 23 :).

Answer (score 1):

If by 1-1 you mean that any task may have one and only one rating, then no other table is needed:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
    ...
    `rating`      int default 1,
    constraint CK_Task_Rating check( rating between 1 and 5 )
)
```

If instead you want each user to be able to rate any task(s), then you need one other table:

```
create table User_Task_Ratings(
    UserID  int not null references Users( ID ),
    TaskID  int not null references Tasks( ID ),
    Rating  int check( Rating between 1 and 5 ),
    constraint PK_User_Task_Ratings primary key( UserID, TaskID )
);
```

Thus each user may give one rating to any task. Technically, this is a many-to-many intersection table between Users and Tasks. But from the point of view of the rating, *this* user may give one and only one rating to *that* task.

If you go with the second alternative, you could still have a rating field in the Task table which could contain, say, the average of all user ratings for that task. However, I would create a view instead that would show task data and calculate the average and probably another field with the number of users who have rated the task. That simplifies maintenance as you don't need to keep a view in synch.